# How to modify spring SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() object after successful login?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working on spring boot application where i've created a CustomUserDetails class by extending UserDetails as follows..

```
public class CustomUserDetails
    extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * The extra field in the login form is for the tenant name
 */
private String tenant;
private Long userId;
private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String role;
```

i need to modify tenant details in UserDetails object. For this i've checked following

[How to update Spring Security UserDetails impls after successful login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608937/how-to-update-spring-security-userdetails-impls-after-successful-login)

https://stackanswers.net/questions/how-to-immediately-enable-the-authority-after-update-user-authority-in-spring-security

https://dev.to/onlineinterview/user-account-loginregistration-feature-with-spring-boot--3fc3

And Controller is here where i'm updating authentication object:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('SUPER_ADMIN')")
@GetMapping(path = "/useTenant/{tenantId}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> useTenant(@PathVariable Long tenantId) {
    HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.OK;
    boolean error = false;
    String message = languageMessageService.getMessage(MultiLanguageKey.SUCCESS);

    // fetch master tenant by id
    Optional<MasterTenant> optional = masterTenantService.findById(tenantId);
    if (optional.isPresent()) {
        CustomUserDetails customUserDetails = customUserDetailsService.getUserDetail();
        //Changing Tenant ID
        customUserDetails.setTenant(optional.get().getTenantId());
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) {
            // Update Current user by changing tenant id in SecurityContextHolder
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;
            auth.setDetails(customUserDetails);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        }
    } else {
        error = false;
        message = languageMessageService.getMessage(MultiLanguageKey.TENANT_NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseDTO(error, message), status);
}
```

My problem is that when i'm hitting another request to perform particular action, i didn't find tenant detail in CustomUserDetails  object which is fetched from

> SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()

Please let me know how can i update or modify UserDetails object of Authentication and save back so another request get updated CustomUserDetails.

Comment: What will be the behavior in case of the second request? Are you able to get the authentication object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UserDetails` should be set to the `Principal` of the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` rather than `Details` as suggested by the [java docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html#getPrincipal--) :

> The AuthenticationManager implementation will often return an
>   Authentication containing richer information as the principal for use
>   by the application. Many of the authentication providers will create a
>   UserDetails object as the principal.

`Details` in `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` is normally stored user 's IP address or certificate serial number etc.

So change it to :

```
 Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
 if (authentication instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) {
        // Update Current user by changing tenant id in SecurityContextHolder
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken currentAuth = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;

        CustomUserDetails userDetail = currentAuth.getPrincipal(); 
        customUserDetails.updateTenanet("blablalb");

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken updateAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetail , 
            currentAuth.getCredentials(),
            currentAuth.getAuthorities());

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(updateAuth);
}
```